# SyntaxError for print function in Atom scripting environment

Tags: python, printing, atom-editor

I am trying to print a list with each item in a separated line:

```
print(*list, sep = '\n')
```

This is the error message I got:

```
File "/Users/wen2019macbookpro/Documents/Coding/Lesson 4/P0/Task4.py", line 52
    print(*list, sep = '\n')
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am also trying to print a list to combine each word into a sentence:

```
print(*['jdoe is', 42, 'years old'])
```

This is the error message I got:

```
File "/Users/wen2019macbookpro/Documents/Coding/Lesson 4/P0/Task4.py", line 52
    print(*['jdoe is', 42, 'years old'])
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this because of the limitation in Atom's scripting environment? I checked other threads and google the syntax, I don't think I am writing anything wrong. But it just can't be executed in Atom.

Comment: You seem to be on Python 2. Get Python 3.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `print(*list, sep = '\n')`, try to print each item on a separate line if there are not too many items, this works and is very straight forward. For the `print(*['jdoe is', 42, 'years old'])`, I am not too sure, it could be related to Atom. It worked for me when I tested it out in a website called "Trinket".